# Couchbase - what happens to old documents on a node when it comes back online?

Tags: couchbase

Suppose I have a Couchbase cluster with 2 data nodes: 1 and 2.

Document X is active on node 1 and replicated on node 2.

Suppose node 1 goes down, and document X is promoted to 'active' on node 2. Node 1 is down for a while; in the meantime, lots of changes are made to document X.

Some time later, node 1 comes back online. Remember that document X was 'active' in node 1.

What happens? It seems like Document X would be active on both nodes. Can Couchbase handle this conflict itself or do I have to do anything in my application code to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go a little deeper, if the vBucket is promoted to active on node 2 that means a failover happened, either manually or automatically. When node 1 comes back up, you will have to add that node back in. If you have not rebalanced yet, you can add the node back in using Delta Node Recovery and the cluster will catch up node 1 from where it left off. The other option is to add that node as if it was a new node and Couchbase will remove and repopulate that node. For a more thorough explanation, [go read the newer 4.5 beta documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/clustersetup/failover.html). It applies to 4.0 and 4.1, and most of it even 3.x as well.

Anyhow, long story short... Couchbase will take care of catching node 1 up where it left off one way or another as that object if it was updated on node 2 while node 1 was down, will get the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by rebalancing at the vBucket level.

According to [this blog post about rebalancing](http://blog.couchbase.com/rebalancing-couchbase-part-i):

> When a client ... is sending requests to the cluster, it takes
>   the key and hashes it against the list of vbuckets. It then looks at
>   the map that it has to determine which server is active for that
>   vbucket. If its map is correct, the server will accept the request...
>   If the vbucket id that the client ... is sending to a server is not active on that
>   server, it will respond with an error saying 'not my vbucket'. During
>   a rebalance, if a client doesn't get updated in time, has some
>   requests 'in flight' or somehow just misses the memo, the old node
>   will respond with a 'not my vbucket' error to any requests after this
>   point in time.

This is an old blog post, but it still applies. Basically, you don't need to worry about conflicts with old documents when a node comes back online.